# jQuery ajax get response not parsed or not seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

The problem is that jQuery does not receive the response by the server, and I can't figure out why. This is my setup, Windows 7 64bit:

### ext.js:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var string= $('#string').val(); 
    $.get('http://localhost:3000', 
        {"input":string}, 
        function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#feedback').text(data);
        }); 
})
```

099.html:

```
<doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <!-- charset title style -->
    <meta charset="uft-8"/> 
    <title>jQuery 099</title>
</head>
<body><!-- tables, div's bad, html 5 is better: -->

    <input type="text" id="string" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="ajax"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
</body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/ext.js"></script>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("got");
    console.log(req.query.input);
    var content = req.query.input;
  res.send(content);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I run node 0.10 from command line using 
C:\dev\nodejs\0.10\servers\stackoverflow>node server.js

In my FF browser i type

```
http://localhost:3000/?input=hi
```

and i get a blank screen containing hi, 
which is good. Also node.js prints got and then hi on the command line

I run 099.html from notepad++ > run > chrome > so it runs on a completely other drive but surely it doesn't need to be in a server, right? When i type something XYZ the textfield and click ajax button, node responds on the console XYZ, which is good: the request is discovered by node, so it would send a response, but i don't see the response in my html. 
The expected behavior was an alert and my div gets filled in the html and displays XYZ.

What obvious point am i missing?

I'm stuck for 2 hours now and couldnt find a similar question perhaps because of my not knowing jquery.

ps the 099 is from the newboston youtube tutorial and jquery is from the jquery site. i don't know the express version, it's a fairly new one.

ps2: the jquery $.get() api is too vague:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ states: "A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds." well, can i conclude that the request succeeded because the nodejs console reacted to it, and if so, why did the callback function not execute.

ps3: the last argument is dataType, perhaps node responds in a way $.get did not expect? any datatype suggestions?

EDIT: yesterday i dusted off my tomcat and put the above files into it and jquery runs like a charm.

How stupid of me, assuming that a file on a disk can communicate over http to a server, what was i thinking.
the essence of ajax is "listening for the asynchronous response" (for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163479.aspx), so the file needs to reside in something that establishes an IP address of some kind obviously. Sorry for polluting the Internet, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter port number when issuing ajax request - this is [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction. See what you can do with [SocketIO](http://socket.io/) instead.

Comment: what do you mean? the port is 3000.

Comment: I mean this is part of code that is not going to work: `$.get('http://localhost:3000',` - specifying port number in URL parameter

Comment: same machine same localhost, same port, same origin policy not violated afaik.